# Static variables vs methods to store properties

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, swiftui

In my SwiftUI application I'm currently using a global struct that holds constants properties like colors or sizes.
E.g.

```swift
struct App {
    struct Colors {
        static let mainAppColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 233/255, green: 230/255, blue: 231/255)
        static let mainWhiteColorMiddleOpacity: UIColor = UIColor.white.opacity(0.5)
    }
}

// usage
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(App.Colors.mainBlueColor)
    }
}
```

I was debating whether this is a bad practice since I have LOTS of static variables, and was wondering if replacing them with static methods or computed properties would decrease memory usage (since body gets computed lots of times). E.g. replacement:

```swift
struct App {
    struct Colors {
        static var mainBlueColor: UIColor { UIColor.blue }
        static var mainWhiteColorMiddleOpacity: UIColor { UIColor.white.opacity(0.5) }
    }
}

// usage
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(App.Colors.mainBlueColor)
    }
}
```

One would increase heap usage and the other stack usage, right?
What do you think would be the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premature (and ill-conceived) optimization. You probably have no idea how little memory is actually taken up by even thousands of these values, in the grand scheme of things; it's trivial. And any decently written app *will* have a lot of them; it's what you do.

A struct is a great way to organize and namespace these sorts of things, although it happens that an enum is now Apple's preferred way (for reasons that I do not entirely understand).

Your "since body gets computed lots of times" is totally irrelevant: the name is a direct reference to the value with absolutely no overhead, since if you use `let` the whole thing is compiled away and replaced by the value right at the point of reference in your code. Lookup time at runtime is zero!

(A computed value or method, on the other hand, might require some serious overhead to run each time, potentially bringing the entire message dispatch mechanism into play, though it might in fact be inlined away perhaps. Serious backsliding there.)

Answer (score 2):

Computed properties are only useful if there is something to compute so the `var`iable makes sense.

You are definitely creating **constants** (as you mentioned), so use `let`

Regarding memory usage: How about declaring colors in the assets catalog?

Comment: Are colors in the assets catalog lighter?

Comment: The asset catalog is a file on disk. It doesn't consume RAM

Answer (score 1):

I would say never use Computed properties for the things you already knows the answer or value, from the other side do you know how many times would SwiftUI run that Computed properties for using it? so many run code for getting the same thing!

you can use Computed properties for the things you need once or some times in your app just for reading value, for example you have a Rectangle that you know the width and height, then use Computed properties for getting the area, or something related like that, after reading value you would be finished with that as well, and there is no need to store it as well.